# whats the recommended approach for create a Front end and Back end same app?

Tags: java

I need to code an application wich Front end and Backend have different templates. Should I make one project with fe and bo in different package same project or, make the core app a web service and make fe and bo two sepparated web sites consuming the web service. Will be a one tier app and is JavaEE

Comment: You don't really expect us to give qualified design advice with so little information? (What kind of "templates" do you mean?)

Comment: I ment the web sites have differents web templates. One is based on an admin template, and the other is a sport site template. Are templates I bouhgt. The thing is they look diferent.

Comment: ... and what are they in *technical* terms? Are we talking about a CSS? A JSF template? Or something else altogether ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the core logic as a Web Service and then create two consumers one for front end and another for back end application; this allows you to keep the changes at one place only.